# nodejs child_processes.exec can not return 'nohup' command

Tags: javascript, shell, node.js

I write a function of nodejs to execute a 'nohup' command and send the success result as http response.

```
function _nohup(cmd,res){
    var child = exec('nohup ./' + cmd + '.sh &',
    function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        res.writeHeader(200);
        res.end("start process success!");
    });
}
```

But when I call the function by the url address, the response data can not return.

Answer (score 6):

`child_process.exec()` waits for the child process to exit and then invokes the callback.  In your case, you've spawned a background process, which presumably isn't ever exiting.

You probably want `child_process.spawn()`:

http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.9/api/child_processes.html#child_process.spawn