# C++ and Node.js Performance when there is high I/O involved

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js

I have a collector system written and compiled in c++, which collects data coming from various sources. (It forks out parallel threads to do the work)

So I run this compiled binary and it collects data and write to different files. The speed at which the data flows to it is around 10 Gbps and writing is also at the same speed (as we write everything without drop).

Now rather than manually running the binary I want to call the main function of that code through GUI/Web Interface. So I read over the internet and thought of using Node.js.

Can you guys please suggest if it will cause my system to slow down (as this is the case of high I/o), I cannot take the slow down under any circumstance.

I am not sure what internally will happen if JavaScript of Node.js calls main function.

Any other idea is also totally welcome.

Comment: You just want an application launcher controlled by a web interface? Did you write the collection system yourself? Does the application finish all by itself when a set of conditions are satisfied?

Comment: I just want it to start from Web UI click.
Yes the Collection system is written by myself.
No its continuous running. Till its process is manually killed from command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your small web application should start another process and then exit. There is no performance penalty for the created process - it's as if you started it manually.

Comment: Yes, the technology you use for the web application is irrelevant in this case. For `node.js` you'd probably use a [child process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) with `.unref()`, although there are other [alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876281/start-new-process-on-nodejs).